# Best RAID level for NAS

Tags: network-attached-storage, raid5, raid1

I just bought my first computer that I'm going to run as a NAS with OpenMediaVault as OS. I bought two HDD (WD red 5400 rpm) with the capacity of 3TB each (and one 120GB SSD that I'm going to run the OS on). Now as I nearly finished the building phase I cant decide if I'm going to use RAID 1 or RAID 5 (have to buy one more disk).
The case I have used is a Node 304 and it has room for a total of 6 HDD/SSD and a motherboard (Gigabyte HA-H97N) that supports 6 SATA.
As I understand I have to choose either RAID 1 or 5 and cannot change afterwards if I decide to go with RAID 1 now.
So, what is your best advice for now and the future when I want to expand the amount of storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you should go RAID1 now and then re-make the whole thing later or go RAID6 or RAID10 (depending on what is possible - RAID10 gives better performance)

With either of those options you have to have at least 4 drives in total.

But don't use RAID5 with that large disks.. You will lose data one day if you do it.

Comment: To go with RAID 1 seems the best solution atm. (until I've filled the space of 3TB). What's the best solution to upgrade from RAID 1 to RAID 6 or 10 when that day comes? Do I need to use a fifth HDD to transfer my 3TB data to and then back to a formatted (empty) RAID 6/10?

Comment: Some RAID controllers support migrating from RAID1 to RAID6/10, otherwise you should use a fifth disk yes.